# jqGrid problems converting and sorting

Tags: jquery, date, jqgrid

I have an issue when sorting dates using `jqGrid`. Given the following dates

`jqGrid` is sorting my dates as follows

```
01/01/2010
01/01/2011
01/02/2010
01/02/2011
```

I would expect to see

```
01/01/2010
01/02/2010
01/01/2011
01/02/2011
```

The column is described as follows:

```
{name:'F_ALTA',index:'F_ALTA',width:60,align:'right'},
```

Seeing lots of answers about this, pero all the answers doesnt work for one reason, the date is completely changed. I mean, if I define the column like this:

```
{name:'F_ALTA',index:'F_ALTA',width:60,align:'right',formatter:'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'m/d/Y'}, datefmt: 'd-M-Y'},
```

The date `17/11/2014` is converted to `05/07/2023` or the date `26/03/2015` is converted to `09/05/2031`.

So that's my problem :P Anybody can give a clue??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost forgot, I'm using jqGrid.src_4.4.6.js

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
{
  name:'F_ALTA',
  index:'F_ALTA',
  width:60,
  align:'right',
  sorttype:'date',
  formatter:'date', 
  formatoptions: {srcformat: 'd/m/Y', newformat:'m/d/Y'}
}
```

There is no need for `datefmt: 'd-M-Y'` and formtoptions should be an object with two options `srcformat` which is current date format and `newformat` as the name suggests new output format for dates.

and i guess you need to have `sorttype:'date'` also.

Comment: The part converting the dates is now working, but the sorting keeps doing weird things, just sorted and I have first several 05/29/2015, after, several 03/26/2015, and after several 11/17/2014, and after 06/01/2015 wich is incorrecta.